# How to print the ASCII value of a int in C++?

Tags: c++, ascii

I'm beginner in c++ and I want to write a program that prints the ASCII value of the alphabet ('a', 'b',.... 'z') and of the numbers ('0'...'9').

I'm able to print the ASCII value of the alphabet using the "int()" function.

Example:

```
char a = 'a';

std::cout<<int(a);
```

The result of the code above was "97", as I expected.

But, I don't know how to print the ASCII value of the numbers. For example, if I have the int 2, I want to get the ASCII value of 2, that it's 48.

I've tried to use the function "int()" but the result it's the int value, not the ASCII value.

Comment: You do the exact same thing, changing what's inside the quotes.

Comment: In your firs sentence you show the numbers as char what happens if you use them as char e.g. char a = '8';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example, if I have the int 2, I want to get the ASCII value of 2, that it's 48.

```
std::cout << (2 + '0');
```

will print the ASCII value of `2`.

If a variable `a` is known to be `0` - `9`, you can use:

```
std::cout << (a + '0');
```

to print the ASCII value corresponding to `a`.

Comment: That works because the C++ standard guarantees that the values of the characters `'0'`, `'1'`, etc. are contiguous, so for example `'0' + 9 == '9'`, even if the system doesn't use an ASCII-based character set. There is no similar guarantee for letters. For example, on an EBCDIC-based system, `'a' + 25 != 'z'`.